# ANTLR4 | Visual Studio 2013 | Portable Code Library

Tags: visual-studio-2013, antlr4, portable-class-library

I'm trying to build a Portable Class Library using ANTLR4. I've added the necessary packages and in a normal project VS allows me to add any of the ANTLR items in the normal add new item way. I do not get the same list when I try to add a new item to a portable class library?

Not sure why it should not allow this?

Martin

Comment: https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs/issues

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug report for a 3rd party tool.

Comment: Hi, not sure why this is off topic? Are we saying that the problem is already known about and will be fixed? Are we just saying that the problem is known about and will not get fixed? Are we saying that I need to ask the question elsewhere? I'll ask the question on the above link.